# Is there any string operators like the POSITION() method of MySQL available in SQLite3?

Tags: string, sqlite

I didn't find it on their doc http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html

So just want to get confirm or options here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Instr, Locate or Splite](http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlite-users@sqlite.org/msg10909.html) it seems **no**, *but you can implement your own*

> I think you will have to write your
>   own user defined function to do this.
>   The SQL standard defines a POSITION()
>   function that returns the position of
>   one string within another, but sqlite
>   doesn't implement it. It should be
>   fairly simple to provide your own
>   function to do this. You can look at
>   the standard functions in func.c for
>   some examples of using the custom
>   function API routines (the same
>   routines are used to define all the
>   standard functions; sum, round,
>   substr, etc.).